# Find the number of distinct numbers in multiplication table

Tags: algorithm

Inspired by [this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table)

Suppose I have a **n** x **n** multiplication table, what is the number of **distinct values** on it?

For example, a 3X3 multiplication table

1  2  3
   2  4  6
   3  6  9

has  **6** unique values namely *[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]*

So far I only have a **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** solution

```
 public static void findDistinctNumbers(int n) {

    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            unique.add(i*j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("number of unique values: " + unique.size());
  }
```

Is there a better approach which is less than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** ?

Comment: The fastest would be `System.out.println("number of unique values: 6");` ;-)

Comment: Well, if you work out `i * j` you certainly don't need to work out `j * i` - that it still `O(n^2)` but is half the work.

Comment: This question *might* be more appropriate over at codereview btw. SO is more about solving problems, and you have already solved this.

Comment: I think this is the best you can do without delving into number theory; I don't see a better way to do this in Java or any other language.  Based on that, I think this should be closed this as not being a question about programming, but as a math question it's definitely interesting.

Comment: To know if a number is unique you must visit each number of the problem. So we get O(n), if it is the exponent that makes you thinking this can be improved. Anyway O(n^2)=O(n^3)=O(n^42). Quite good. O(2^n) that is bad.

Comment: If there were a formula for π(x), the prime counting function, it could be solved in O(1). ;-)

Comment: I think if you subtract the number of prime numbers between n and n^2 from n^2 you will get the answer. This csn be done efficiently by sieving.

Comment: @user1990169 Thank you for explaining my comment - but computing the sieve is O(n^2).

Comment: Computing the sieve is NOT O(n²) - it is considerably faster, since each inner loop is faster than the previous one. The estimate is O(N log log N)

Comment: I'm fairly confident a sieve approach could work better.

Comment: @user1990169 Even in the 3x3 example we have 8, which is beteen n and n^2 but neither a prime nor part of the solution.

Comment: @tucuxi except that in this case `N = n²`; `n` is the dimension along one side of the table.

Comment: @MarkRansom please ignore capitalization. You can run the sieve in O(n log log n), where n is the number of numbers that you are running it on.

Comment: @laune Can I see your algorithm for solving it in O(1) given O(1) lookup for π(x)? Because building π(x) is NOT O(n^2), but considerably less

Comment: Numerical solutions for n = 1 .. 53 are given at [oeis.org/A027424](http://oeis.org/A027424), along with a link for solutions up to n = 1000. Unless I am reading them incorrectly, all the formulas and code given there are O(n^2). I have not yet checked the links to Ford, Koukoulopoulos, or Pomerance. Fun question! But math, not programming.

Comment: @tucuxi: The point that you're not getting and that others have tried to explain is that in the OP's example, `n` is 3. So his method is O(n^2). The Sieve, as you've pointed out, is O(n log log n), where `n` is the number of items you're running it against. In this case, you have to run it against 9 items. So the Sieve is O(n^2 log(log(n^2))), where *n == 3*.

Comment: @JimMischel no, I am running the sieve only against n, not n². See my answer below as to how I am using it.

Comment: In Python, I'd dump the numbers into a set and take the len of the set. Not sure what that is in big O notation, though, but I think it's better than n^2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that to use a set to verify the uniqueness, you have to populate it first, and it's O(n^2), one way or another;
without a set, you can't easily verify if a number is unique or not...

As a side note: since big-O class is somewhat broad (i.e. it can describe any complexity *not higher* than something, but not necessarily
*not lower*, ie. both linear complexity and quadratic complexity algorithms can be described as O(n^2), since, in both cases, the complexity
*is not higher* than n^2) - as such, assume that every O(x) in this answer means "Big Theta", ie. asymptotical up/down boundary, such that
f(n) is in O(g(n)) means that k1*g(n)<=f(n)<=k2*g(n) (k1,k2 positive of course).

As https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108912/number-of-elements-in-the-set-1-cdots-n-times-1-cdots-n?lq=1 points out, the exact amount is
 asymptotically approaching a well-known value; even so, the *exact* value for any given `n` is not something that can be calculated simply,
  as, in essence, it's quite similar to solving http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function -

that said, let's try to summarize the facts, "(why?)" marking the fields I'm too lazy/tired to explain ATM, but which an interested reader
may verify (or disprove) himself:

a) no well-known formula to get the result by a simple function a(n) currently exists,

b) because of that, we are required to generate a set with all of the unique numbers and return the cardinality of that set as the result,

c) since the amount of actual numbers in the set is proven to be o(n^2) (see the reference), strictly speaking o(n^2/(log n)^c * (loglog n)^3/2),
 generating the set would take at least that much operations - that's our low bound - assuming *we already know if a number is in the set or not*,

d) as such, complexity C of our algorithm A can be though, at best, to be such that

O(n^2) > O(C) > O(n^2/(log n)^c * (loglog n)^3/2) (please note that this represents only *minuscule* improvement over pure n^2).

That said, my proposition for A goes as follows:

a) since the matrix is symmetric vs the diagonal, assume we're analysing only e.g. upper right triangle plus diagonal

b) assume that, for your n, any number x =< n is in the set

c) calculate y=int(sqrt(n)) - every diagonal value of row r <= y is already present in the set, every diagonal value of row r > y
has to be checked

c') n*(n+1)/2-n-int(sqrt(n)) elements need to be processed (added to set) in the "conventional" method

d) now, since we ruled out all the values that can be predicted easily, we enter the main loop:
for (row r < n) // max number is r * n
  all x : x > (r-1) * n are guaranteed to be unique *till now*, so they needn't be processed, assuming we *wouldn't have to maintain unique numbers set!*;
  since the row's set is for numbers (r^2;r*n), all numbers in range ((r-1)*n,r*n) in row r are in range
  now, since the actual set of numbers in row r is a_n = r, 2*r, 3*r ... n*r, the obvious problem is to find
  a "border" integer y*r such that y*r > (r-1)*n, because that would mean that we have n-y guaranteed uniques.
  nb if we find an exact value of ((r-1)*n)/r to be an integer, we can safely assume that y = ((r-1)*n)/r + 1 (why?),
  and that exact integer is not unique.
  because of this, there is exactly max(n-r,ceil(n/r)) guaranteed uniques in every row (why?); we get this in O(1)  for every row

e) the trickiest part: we've got some number >= than r*r, but obviously smaller than (r-1)*n;
  that is the "hard range", [r*r, (r-1)*n) , in which the number can be or not be unique;
  we can have at most i_r = max(0,n-r-floor(n/r)) numbers to check this range (why?)
  even naive checking every number in this range is obviously faster than O(n) (why? -floor(n/r) factor grows with respect to n !)

we already got better than O(n^2) - we have sum(i_r) iterations, for r = 2..n (first row is no-op), so this is actually equal to
  sum for r=2..n(max(0,n-r-floor(n/r))) - I won't provide an exact complexity class result here, as it's not a pretty number,
  Let's try to go even further...

f) What about a catapult?

g) For odd rows, we can't do much more (since this would, amongst many things, require us to solve some prime-related
  problems, already mentioned in the comments, which hasn't been solved for world's best matematicians yet) - yet we still can
  help ourselves for every even r!

divide r by two. every number that is <= r/2 * n *has already been processed! it's either unique or not, we don't have to care!*.

Note that since we actually dropped the ends of the rows already (and most of the beginnings too), this works surprisingly good.
  Since we do this check only on even rows, we just start checking them (adding to set) not from x = r*(r+1), but from r/2*n+r instead!

h) but now, the most important thing: **how to check them if we don't have a set of already found uniques defined**? sadly, this is the main
   problem with *any* algorithm that tries to go below ~n*n/2 element iterations
    - since you don't process all values, how can you know if the value has been processed or not?

i) if there was an easy way to predict how many (eg. %) of the "potentially unique" numbers are really unique, there won't be any real problem here,
   it would be a O(n) problem - but I simply consider it impossible, due to above difficulties.

---

tl;dr - I call shenanigans on any answer trying to do it strictly below O(n^2) - you can drop a few bits below, but the complexity class won't get reduced anyway.

Comment: If you need to iterate n², then there is obviously no way to go below n². I've been trying to find an incremental answer, but oeis.org/A108407 is hard to crack.

Comment: My god. If anyone actually solve this, he/she better be writing a paper than a SO answer.

Comment: The problem is not *similar* to counting the primes, it is *exactly the same* as counting the primes. The answer is n^2 minus the number of primes between n and n^2, since every number between n and n^2 must be either divisible by a number between 2 and n or it must be prime.

Comment: @MarkRansom no mark, that's wrong. I actually made a failed attempt based on that 'minus things divisible by primes between n and n^2'. There is a simple counter example: in the `n=3` case, `8` is not in the multiplication table and also not divisible by any prime between `3` and `9`. Another example to convince you: take `n=9`, then `75` is also not divisible by any primes between `9` and `81`.

Comment: @Billiska no I said "between 2 and n". 8 is divisible by 2 and 75 is divisible by 5. That part of the statement wasn't part of the formula, it was the justification for the formula. To say the formula another way, the answer is all of the numbers 1 through n plus all of the non-primes n+1 through n^2.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No. Look at A027424, the link by Noe. a(664) = 112300. But by your calculation 664 * 664 = 440986, PrimePi[440986] = 37018. PrimePi[664] = 121, and 440986 - 37018 + 121 = 404089, which is far different from 112300.

Comment: @user448810 thanks, I see my mistake now - it's not enough to remove the primes, you must also remove all numbers that can't be factored with one of the factors being n or less. You don't see it with small n.

Comment: @Billiska my apologies, it was late when I saw your examples and I didn't think them through. The first one of 8 not appearing in the 3x3 table is perfect.

Comment: Why is your lower bound O(n^2/(log n)^c * (loglog n)^3/2)? Aren't you assuming that the only way to find A(n) is to look at all the numbers? Big assumption!

Comment: @tucuxi since no-one for 60 years has been able to find a functional formula for a(n), I don't consider this "a big assumption", for exactly the same reason I won't call saying "there's no simple formula for determining if n is a prime factor of m short of division" or "there's not simple way to find if a number is prime" a "big assumption". I'd rather call a person saying otherwise to be making **big assumptions** about his math skills. Point a) - *no well-known formula to get the result by a simple function a(n) currently exists,* - is the only assumption I made.

Comment: I do not know if people have really sought to find something more efficient, computational-complexity wise, and neither do you (or you should really cite sources). "A(n) from scratch" and "A(n) given all previous A(i) and any other intermediate results" are different problems. One thing is the existence of an analytical mathematical formula, and another (related, but not exactly the same) thing is computational complexity. Most mathematicians do not concern themselves with the latter - the papers you cited below, for example.

Comment: @tucuxi they are *not* different problems - recursive equations are very common way of expressing functional formulas, and, believe me or not, the problem with reducing complexity of the algorithm by an order of magnitude *is* an area of interest of computational mathematics.

Comment: I would be happy to see sources. For instance, I found no references to complexity classes when scanning the arxiv papers that you mentioned below. Do you know of any by computational mathematicians? Would improving the current bounds of this problem be of any applied interest, and has it therefore received significant expert scrutiny from such specialists? (btw: answering this in your answer would be a significant improvement)

Comment: @tucuxi a) "I do not know if people have really sought to find something more efficient, computational-complexity wise, and neither do you (or you should really cite sources)" - I can't cite sources for something that *doesn't exist*. You're trying to shift the burden of proof in absurd way. I can't prove that nobody hasn't found a better way - I haven't found anybody who found a better way, and thus I conclude that nobody, as far as I know, have found it. Another thing is - if you'd read the Koukoulopoulos on this, you'd actually notice his description of the problem *is* recursive.

Comment: Also, computational complexity of an algorithm *is* directly related to the algorithm used, which is, in turn, directly related to the mathematical formula used to generate the result. If you'd found an algorithm with a lower complexity, you'd actually found a better mathematical formula to solve the problem. It's common knowledge that calculating the value of a(n) = k*a(n-1) + l would be in complexity class O(n), while calculating a sum of all elements in n*n matrix would be O(n^2); I saw no paper stating this explicitly, does that mean the complexity classes are unknown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57125/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-tucuxi).

Comment: @vaxquis your answer contradicts itself - the low-bound you mention in the first `c)` becomes infinitely smaller than `n^2` as `n` grows to infinity.

Comment: @whateverisyournick You can't approach infinity with a computational algorithm. If you think you can do so, go ahead, I won't stop you.

Comment: @vaxquis Will Ness helped me see that you are correct - `A(n)` is only smaller than `n^2` by a constant factor rather than an order of magnitude.

Comment: Here is an O(n) solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714104/how-to-solve-erdos-uniques-multiples-in-o-an/24828545#24828545

Comment: IFTFY: *an O(n^2)* solution, exactly the same as proposed by OP, only in C, not Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714104/how-to-solve-erdos-uniques-multiples-in-o-an/24828545#24828545

Comment: @גלעדברקן further proof: ideone.com/5erYHE (excuse me for changing the formatting of the code, but I prefer C99 style to ANSI C) - iterator gets (as obviously expected) exactly n^2/2 iterations as n->inf

Comment: @vaxquis no, vaxquis you are wrong. The solutions look similar to you. The algorithm David proposed, calculates ALL A(n) for n between 1 and N. The answer for any one particular n in David's answer takes n iterations to produce.

Comment: @גלעדברקן http://ideone.com/LVG6Qb - you've got the very same algorithm OP used; the only difference is *one* conditional check added. The complexity is still O(n^2) - please, test the snippets if you don't understand it. Computational complexity of the task is based on calculating *the whole* task, not a linear part of it - since you have n linear parts, each with O(n) complexity, you get a O(n^2) as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that *there is a better-than O(n²) solution*. I have not been able to find it, but I believe I am on the right path, just a few mathematical insights away.

This is my algorithm-under-development:

```
public static int numberOfDistinctResults(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    // runs a prime-number sieve in O(n log log n)
    Factorization.initialize(n); 
    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
        // divs[i] == 0 iff i is prime, or the lowest prime that divides i
        if (Factorization.divs[i] == 0) {
            // i is prime; for all j<=i, j*i is brand new; nothing to substract
        } else {
            // i is non-prime; discard already-seen decompositions
            total -= magic(n); // <--- this part needs work
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Currently, this runs in under O(n²) as long as `magic(n)` can run in under O(n). However, I have been unable to find such a `magic` function. Essentially, I am adding terms from [oeis.org/A062854](http://oeis.org/A062854/graph) -- there appears to be a lot of structure in that graph.

See [oeis.org/A027424](http://oeis.org/A027424) for a lot of background on the whole question (all the algorithms listed seem to be O(n²), though), and [oeis.org/A108407](http://oeis.org/A108407) for a list of values for `magic(n)` and several related sequences. A small table of values follows, where you can see that primes are easy (0 to substract), but non-primes are hard (no immediately apparent relation to factorization or existing factors):

```
f(1) = 1 ( prev + 1 = 1 - 0)
f(2) = 3 ( prev + 2 = 2 - 0)
f(3) = 6 ( prev + 3 = 3 - 0)
f(4) = 9 ( prev + 3 = 4 - 1)
    4 = 2^2; available = 2·3
f(5) = 14 ( prev + 5 = 5 - 0)
f(6) = 18 ( prev + 4 = 6 - 2)
    6 = 2·3; available = 2^2·3·5
f(7) = 25 ( prev + 7 = 7 - 0)
f(8) = 30 ( prev + 5 = 8 - 3)
    8 = 2^3; available = 2^2·3·5·7
f(9) = 36 ( prev + 6 = 9 - 3)
    9 = 3^2; available = 2^3·3·5·7
f(10) = 42 ( prev + 6 = 10 - 4)
    10 = 2·5; available = 2^3·3^2·5·7
f(11) = 53 ( prev + 11 = 11 - 0)
f(12) = 59 ( prev + 6 = 12 - 6)
    12 = 2^2·3; available = 2^3·3^2·5·7·11
f(13) = 72 ( prev + 13 = 13 - 0)
f(14) = 80 ( prev + 8 = 14 - 6)
    14 = 2·7; available = 2^3·3^2·5·7·11·13
f(15) = 89 ( prev + 9 = 15 - 6)
    15 = 3·5; available = 2^3·3^2·5·7·11·13
f(16) = 97 ( prev + 8 = 16 - 8)
    16 = 2^4; available = 2^3·3^2·5·7·11·13
f(17) = 114 ( prev + 17 = 17 - 0)
f(18) = 123 ( prev + 9 = 18 - 9)
    18 = 2·3^2; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17
f(19) = 142 ( prev + 19 = 19 - 0)
f(20) = 152 ( prev + 10 = 20 - 10)
    20 = 2^2·5; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17·19
f(21) = 164 ( prev + 12 = 21 - 9)
    21 = 3·7; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17·19
f(22) = 176 ( prev + 12 = 22 - 10)
    22 = 2·11; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17·19
f(23) = 199 ( prev + 23 = 23 - 0)
f(24) = 209 ( prev + 10 = 24 - 14)
    24 = 2^3·3; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17·19·23
f(25) = 225 ( prev + 16 = 25 - 9)
    25 = 5^2; available = 2^4·3^2·5·7·11·13·17·19·23
f(26) = 239 ( prev + 14 = 26 - 12)
    26 = 2·13; available = 2^4·3^2·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23
f(27) = 254 ( prev + 15 = 27 - 12)
    27 = 3^3; available = 2^4·3^2·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23
f(28) = 267 ( prev + 13 = 28 - 15)
    28 = 2^2·7; available = 2^4·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23
f(29) = 296 ( prev + 29 = 29 - 0)
f(30) = 308 ( prev + 12 = 30 - 18)
    30 = 2·3·5; available = 2^4·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29
f(31) = 339 ( prev + 31 = 31 - 0)
f(32) = 354 ( prev + 15 = 32 - 17)
    32 = 2^5; available = 2^4·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
f(33) = 372 ( prev + 18 = 33 - 15)
    33 = 3·11; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
f(34) = 390 ( prev + 18 = 34 - 16)
    34 = 2·17; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
f(35) = 410 ( prev + 20 = 35 - 15)
    35 = 5·7; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
f(36) = 423 ( prev + 13 = 36 - 23)
    36 = 2^2·3^2; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
f(37) = 460 ( prev + 37 = 37 - 0)
f(38) = 480 ( prev + 20 = 38 - 18)
    38 = 2·19; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37
f(39) = 501 ( prev + 21 = 39 - 18)
    39 = 3·13; available = 2^5·3^3·5^2·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37
```

Comment: although I like the very idea you proposed, finding this magic(n) would essentially mean you either disproved or solved the problem defined by Erdos, Kevin Ford and Dimitris Koukoulopoulos ... see  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401223, http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1072 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3236 - I'm not saying with perfect confidence that you can't do that, but, until you do and thus are able to actually *solve* the problem instead of *being convinced of being able to solve the problem*, I'm inclined to downvote.

Comment: I am not convinced that *I* can solve it, but I am convinced that *magic(n) is computable in under O(n), with any suitable pre-computed intermediate results available* (two very different things). Please indicate which theorem in the above papers contradicts these italics - I have found none. You are, of course, free to downvote as your inclinations tell you. My answer may not be a true answer -- but none of them currently are: some are wrong, and none is conclusive proof in any direction.

Comment: I written explicitly *or solved* - if you're able to solve the problem of your "magic(n)", you'll essentially solve the problems described in those papers in a better and more streamlined way. Your beliefs are only that, beliefs. You believe you're right, I believe you're wrong. Without proof, your making a religion out of science. The burden of proof is on the one proposing a new solution or disproving existing ones, not otherwise. Your answer is *not* a true answer (no "may" here), as it only describes your convictions, not solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there is a better algorithm, which runs in subquadratic time.  See this recent paper of [Brent, Pomerance, Purdum, and Webster](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04251). Their algorithm also outputs all the values in the **n** x **n** multiplication table.  Note that the number of values is known to be subquadratic, due to a classic result of [Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tenenbaum%E2%80%93Ford_constant).  The linked [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table/400593#400593) on MathOverflow has more information.